# creating an array and append values to it in smarty template

Tags: append, smarty

I want to create an array in smarty and do an append functionality in it! Like if I declare a variable in smarty template like `{assign var=sizearr value=''}` and then i want to append values to this in a loop, and i can access values like `{sizearr.0}`,  how can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use [append](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.append.tpl). I'm not sure if this is also available in Smarty 2

`{append var='sizearr' value='' index=0}`

Answer (score 2):

In smarty3 yould also use a more php-like approach:

```
{$sizearr[] = 'your value'}
```

and either loop through the array like

```
{foreach $sizearr as $value}
  {$value@key}: {$value}
{/foreach}
```

or just hit a specific index:

```
{$sizearr[2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this too:

```
{$sizearr[] = "Size value"}
```

[Here you can see the full doc (Section Appending an array)](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.builtin.functions.tpl#language.function.shortform.assign)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the smarty built-in function [append](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.append.tpl) :

Now lets take this example:

```
{assign var="ages" value=[] }

{for $i=1 to 3}
   {append var="ages" value=$i }
{/for}
```

In the above example we didn't specify **index** parameter in the **append** function, so the value will be appended at the end of the **ages** array.

Hope this is helpful for everyone.